# How to find Group Policy settings for related Microsoft Office options ?

Tags: microsoft-office, group-policy

I have been looking for a mapping between the options you see on the Office 2010 applications and the equivalents for setting through group policy but I have been unable to find something that is at the level of "to set screen option x do y in group policy". Does such a thing exist?

As a specific example, one setting we wish to control centrally is the Office Trust Centre privacy option "Automatically detect installed office applications to improve office.com search results". I can find no document that lists this option and shows the equivalent group policy setting.

I have been able to ascertain some options through Google (leading to sites like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179123.aspx)) but I am finding it a struggle to cover everything. Managers may say things like "we need to disable X" but there is no logical path to how to achieve that through gpo.

Any help guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to download the Office Group Policy ADM/ADMX files for post deployment configuration (pre deployment configuration uses OCT for these settings).

[Microsoft Download: Office 2010 Administrative Template files (ADM, ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18968)